# Executing untrusted RDotNet code

Tags: .net, r.net

We are working on a feature where we need to let the user write a small R script to calculate some data.

Scripts are supposed to be pretty simple like:

```
var1 + var2 - var3
```

or

```
var1 + sum(var2)
```

However, R can do much more than this and we do not want anybody to execute stuff on our servers.

We have tried using a different AppDomain but this [link](https://rdotnet.codeplex.com/workitem/92) seems to show that it is still not supported.

So we need to find some more creative way to "secure" the server.

One option we have thought of is to create some kind of dictionary of allowed function and pre-parse the script to find things that would not be allowed.

My question is: how would you do it? (provided that AppDomain is NOT an option)

Comment: Not sure if thats a comment or an answer, I'd stick to the app domain, but via a different way: you might try to run your application within a different process, which already runs within a different app domain. In that case R.net and R will still be used in a single domain. If I'm not mistaken the R process itself starts automatically in the same domain as its parent. The inter-process comunication could be realised via i.e. MCF named pipes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the sake of marking this question as closed, here is what we did:

We ended up using [Rserve](https://rforge.net/Rserve/).

This is hosted on a machine that can't do anything fancy and security is then managed at machine/user level rather than in the process.